How to make custom SKU text in WooComerce WordPress?
I need to replace the standard text "SKU:" with the "#" character, but my code doesn't do it the way I want it to. It leaves the colon character ":" at the end

I wrote this code, but the colon character remains
function translate_woocommerce($translation, $text, $domain) {
    if ($domain == 'woocommerce') {
        switch ($text) {
            case 'SKU:':
                $translation = '#';
                break;
            case 'SKU':
                $translation = '#';
                break;
        }
    }
    return $translation;
}

add_filter('gettext', 'translate_woocommerce', 10, 3);


Hi @dSofarts, did you try logging $translation, $text and $domain before your if statement? I think that will be the first thing to do, your current theme could be overriding the template too. Also try changing the priority of the hook and see if anything changes.

Which WordPress theme do you use?

I'm using Impreza theme

I did something similar with chanting the word items to item.
function change_woocommerce_item_text($translation, $single, $plural, $number, $context, $domain) {
    if ($domain == 'Divi' && ($translation == '%1$s Item' || $translation == '%1$s Items')) {
        return '%1$s';
    }
    return $translation;
}


Hi, thanks, but that doesn't help
